# Extract cells/Ranges information(col,row) from selected area in active Excel sheet with Python win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com

For my python script, there is one missing simple trick when I want to take data from Excel with Python win32com.

I just want to know how to get selected cells information, e.g. col/row for my python script. For example I could specify the range as shown below, but I simply cannot do the same thing to the selected/active cells.

```
ws.Range("B1:AM167").CopyPicture()
```

Does someone help me with this?
I am quite new to win32, so I still do not know how to find correct method/property etc...

Comment: Perhaps [Application.Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.selection?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel__Application_Selection). "The returned object type depends on the current selection (for example, if a cell is selected, this property returns a Range object). The Selection property returns Nothing if nothing is selected."

Comment: Thank you very much Justin! Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Application.Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.selection?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel__Application_Selection).

> The returned object type depends on the current selection (for
> example, if a cell is selected, this property returns a Range object).
> The Selection property returns Nothing if nothing is selected.